# My Google Apps Script code gives me a "TypeError: blahblah is not a function" when calling "Array[I][0].indexOf(String)" in a "for(){" loop

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

So I'm making an invoicing program that pulls my schedule from my Google Calendar and (will hopefully) automatically populate an invoice that I can save and send to my clients. It's going really well so far, except when I try to iterate through the spreadsheet and check the ".indexOf" a string in the values of an array--I get a "TypeError: rngNamesSearch[i][0].indexOf is not a function" and the code just stops ONLY when that line of code is called with in the "for(){" loop.

What gives? (and thank you in advance for any insight and help you can offer)

Here's the section of problematic code:

```
function createInvoice(){
/* //this stuff is all fine

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetGetEvents = ss.getSheetByName("GCal Import");

  var dRngGetEvents = sheetGetEvents.getDataRange();
  var rngNamesSearch = dRngGetEvents.getValues();
  var rngNamesMatch = [];
  var namesMatchCount = 0;

  var prompt_customerName = ui.prompt("Please enter the customer's name, as found in the calendar");
  var customerName = new String(prompt_customerName.getResponseText());

*/
//here is where the problems occur 

  Browser.msgBox("The customer name is " + customerName);
  Browser.msgBox((rngNamesSearch[5][0]).indexOf(customerName)); //this attempt at finding the “indexOf” works just fine

  for(var i = 0;i<rngNamesSearch.length;i++){
    Browser.msgBox(rngNamesSearch[i][0]); //this attempt ALSO works just fine
    Browser.msgBox((rngNamesSearch[i][0]).indexOf(customerName)); //***THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK***//
    var nameIndex = ((rngNamesSearch[i][0]).indexOf(customerName)); //this line probably doesn't work either...
    if(nameIndex > -1){
      rngNamesMatch[namesMatchCount]=[];
      rngNamesMatch[namesMatchCount].push(rngNamesSearch[i][0],rngNamesSearch[i][2]);
      namesMatchCount++;
    }
  }  
/* //more extra unproblematic code
  var sheetInvoice = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  var outputRng = sheetInvoice.getRange(2,1,rngNamesMatch.length,2);
  outputRng.setValues(rngNamesMatch);
*/
}
```

I tried writing Array[i][0].indexOf(customerName) in so many different parts of code--within the function, in a new function, etc. and it all worked perfectly. It just doesn't work in a "for" loop, and I'm stumped as to why and what I need to do instead. I haven't found an answer yet in my search, or else I would have fixed the problem by now. So I made an account here to ask for help. Thank you to all who took time to consider my problem, and extra thanks to those who can provide a solution.

Comment: "nameIndex > -1" - you _think_ that you are searching within an array since [indexOf() returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) BUT... `rngNamesSearch[i][0]` returns the value of a specific cell within the array and in fact you are searching within a string. I suggest that you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), AND provide an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: The behavior of the code is just fine. My problem is: my code crashes with a “TypeError” when it gets to the line labeled ///***THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK***///. When I use .indexOf anywhere else in the code, it works fine. When I try it in the “for” loop, it crashes.

I can’t really provide a successful outcome since my code crashes instead of outputting anything. Again, the intended behavior is just fine—it’s the mysterious crash I get when trying to find the “.indexOf” the value in the array within the “for” loop. And I have no idea why it crashes and produces an error.

Comment: "I can’t really provide a successful outcome" You could IF you shared some data that you have run through your script and which generates the error, and you could provide an example of the output that you are trying to achieve if your script was successful. With respect, as it stands we don't know how much data you have, what sort of data, we don't know what `rngNamesSearch` returns, or a value of `customerName`, or the values of `nameIndex` for each iteration of the loop; we don't have any troubleshooting/debug information. We have no data to reproduce your error.